# Unit test runs okay when invoked manually, but are completely ignored by PyDev

Tags: python, unit-testing, pydev

I have a made a simple unit test like this:

```
import unittest

class TestParsing(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_vgm_1_01(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

If I run it through PyDev's `Run As -> Python Run`, that is, if I run it as a normal program, relying on direct invocation of `unittest.main()`, it works exactly as expected:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

On the other hand, if it is executed via `Run As -> Python unit-test`, it simply does not work:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Does anyone have an idea of why wouldn't this be working as expected?

The current PyDev project is available at https://github.com/haroldo-ok/vgmparse/tree/support-vgm-1.01

Comment: What is the file name?

Comment: The filename is "test.py"